# Is passing ORM entities into templates acceptable in MVC pattern frameworks?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, orm, separation-of-concerns

Is passing ORM entities directly into templates acceptable?

In a hypothetical python framework is this worse

```
def fetch_widgets:
    widgets = widget.fetch("price < 50")
    render_template('widget.html', widgets=widgets)
```

than this?

```
def fetch_widgets:
    widgets = [(w.name, w.price) for w in widget.fetch("price < 50")]
    render_template('widget.html', widgets=widgets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template engine is only capable of *retrieving* models, then sure. It's when templates are used to *manipulate* models that the walls break down.